# i want to write a php script to find if a given number is prime or not

Tags: php

I have tried to create a code which is

```html
<html>
<body>
 <form method = "post"> 
  <?php
          Number : <input type = "text" name = "prime">;
          <input type = "submit" value ="Submit">;
          $num = $_REQUEST["prime"];
          $flag = 0;
          for($i = 2; $i <= $num/2; $i++)
          {
   if( $num % $i == 0)
   {
           $flag = 1;
              break;
          }
          }
          if($flag == 0)
   echo "$num is a prime number";
          else
   echo "$num is not a prime number";
  ?>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever i try to run it, i get the error
    **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in 
    C:\xampp\htdocs\pc.php on line 5**

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your `<?php` tag should be a couple of lines down - just before `$num =`

Comment: Although there are quite a few other problems once you get past the syntax.

Comment: Everything between `<?php` and `?>` must be valid PHP code. You have HTML at the start.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is wrong. There is no statement in line 5. Corrected code:

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='post'){
        $num = $_POST["prime"];
        $flag = 0;
        for($i = 2; $i <= $num/2; $i++)
        {
            if( $num % $i == 0)
            {
                $flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($flag == 0)
            echo $num." is a prime number";
        else
            echo $num." is not a prime number";
    }
?>
    <form method = "post" action="#">
        Number : <input type = "text" name = "prime">
        <input type = "submit" value ="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This will check current request method. If is is pot

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the below procedure for solving your problem

```
 <html>
<body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['prime']))
        {
            $num = $_POST["prime"];
            $flag = 0;
            for($i = 2; $i <= $num/2; $i++)
            {
                if( $num % $i == 0)
                {
                    $flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
                if($flag == 0)
                    echo "$num is a prime number";
                else
                    echo "$num is not a prime number";
        }


    ?>
    <form method = "post"> 
        <input type = "text" name="prime">
        <input type = "submit" value ="Submit">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```